# Create regex to check domain and URL

Tags: php, regex, youtube

Can someone please help me build regex to make sure that a string starts with one of the following?

```
https://www.youtube.com
https://www.youtube.be
http://www.youtube.com
http://www.youtube.be
https://youtube.com
https://youtube.be
http://youtube.com
http://youtube.be
www.youtube.com
www.youtube.be
youtube.com
youtube.be
```

I am working in on PHP system that allows people to add a YouTube video to a web page, I only need to make sure that the link users add begins appropriately and is also a valid URL. That should be then be safe enough for the string to be stored after the user has entered it and also embedded as a YouTube video when viewed later.

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/ is a very well made site to learn regex and try out this kind of things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's as simple as

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtube\.(be|com)
```

Little bit of explanation:

- `^` - start of the string
- `https?` - `http` with optional `s`
- `:\/\/` - `://`
- `(www\.)?` - optional `www.`
- `youtube\.` - `youtube.`
- `(be|com)` - `be` or  `com`

---

If you also want to match `youtu.be`, use this:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.(be|com)|youtu\.be)
```

Comment: Does that check for http and https?

Comment: Thanks. Will test later when back on the job and report back.

Comment: @Peter added explanation in case you don't understand something immediately.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for your answer and the additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www.)?youtu(?:\.?be)?\.(?:com|be))
```

Includes:

```
https://www.youtube.com
https://www.youtube.be
http://www.youtube.com
http://www.youtube.be
https://youtube.com
https://youtube.be
http://youtube.com
http://youtube.be
www.youtube.com
www.youtube.be
youtube.com
youtube.be
youtu.be
www.youtu.be
http://www.youtu.be
https://www.youtu.be
http://youtu.be
https://youtu.be
```

PHP:

```
$re = "/((?:https?:\\/\\/)?(?:www.)?youtu(?:\\.?be)?\\.(?:com|be))/"; 
$str = "https://www.youtube.com\nhttps://www.youtube.be\nhttp://www.youtube.com\nhttp://www.youtube.be\nhttps://youtube.com\nhttps://youtube.be\nhttp://youtube.com\nhttp://youtube.be\nwww.youtube.com\nwww.youtube.be\nyoutube.com\nyoutube.be\nyoutu.be\nwww.youtu.be\nhttp://www.youtu.be\nhttps://www.youtu.be\nhttp://youtu.be\nhttps://youtu.be\n\n\nbsadf.fds\n\nyoutube\.(be|com)"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

UPD:
Yes, @nicael is right, but I would change so:

```
((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.(?:be|com)|youtu\.be))
```

Comment: OP didn't really ask for `youtu.be`. Although, you've implemented it incorrectly anyway. Matches `youtu.com`, for example.